# Normal map texture not working with cylindrical objects in Evee Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling

I've applied normal maps to two surfaces in the attached image. One is the red tentacle looking shape and the other is the blue tube that wraps around the disc. I can't see any texture in those objects. I used the exact same method to apply a normal map to the disc and you can see the texture applied there. I don't know why it works on the disc in this picture but not on the red tentacle or the tube. The only difference afaik between the disc and the two objects that aren't displaying textures is that they are both sort cylinder shaped.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!
[image]
[image]

Comment: as Juztcode says, it's hard to tell, please pack the images inside the file (File > External Data > Pack All Into Blend) and share it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say anything without the .blend but, the problem most likely lies because you've used the same UV map for different objects and the normal map is not being adjusted to the different UV scales

Comment: OKay, thanks. I'll give it a try. I'm very new to this (2 weeks). Difficult to understand many of the concepts.

Comment: yeah, you can comment here back if any problemos ;-)